# Save HTML-Form Content as User?

Tags: forms, save

I have a external Website with an HTML-Form. Is it possible that I can save the content I filled in and than close that website. Than revisiting the site a few days later and somehow re-insert the content I originally filled in?

Comment: Exactly, what do you want?

Comment: @Sunderam you know, if you fill out a regular HTML-Form... if you simply refresh that page the form is cleared... is there a way to preserve the information?

Comment: No it's html property, sometimes it's preseved but if you hard refresh it, `ctrl+f5`, so it will disappear.

Comment: But why you want to preserve?

Comment: @Sunderam it is a really long form, where data from many different sources has to be inserted... it would be really beneficial if i not have to write in everything in on one day...